# How I disable highlighting a row in DojoGrid on mouseover (preferably using WaveMaker)

Tags: dojox.grid

I can for instance hide the header row of a DojoGrid in WaveMaker by doing the following:

```
body.tundra .Main .wmlayout .Main-clubsDojoGrid .dojoxGridHeader{
     display: none;
}
```

Is there something similar I can do to stop a row being highlighted upon mouseover?

Comment: See this post http://dev.wavemaker.com/forums/?q=node/6478#comment-23027 for changing the background color of the mouseover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the style rule used by the themes engine; replace .wm_template with your theme name (.wm_default)

```
/* Custom mouse-over color for rows */
.wm_template .wmlist-item.wmlist-item-over,
.dj_ie6 .wm_template .wmlist-item.wmlist-item-over,
.wm_template div.dojoxGrid-row.dojoxGrid-row-over, 
.wm_template .dojoxGrid-row.dojoxGrid-row-odd.dojoxGrid-row-over,
.wm_template .dojoxGridRowOver, 
.wm_template .dojoxGridRowOdd.dojoxGridRowOver,
.wm_template #wavemakerNode .wmlayout .dojoxGridRowOdd.dojoxGridRowOver a,
.wm_template .dojoxGridRowOver td.dojoxGridCell
{
    /* Document-ClickablesHover-Background */
    background-color: #333333; /* Document-ClickablesHover-Background_Color */

    /* Document-ClickablesHover-Font */
    color: #FFFFFF; /* Document-ClickablesHover-Font_Color */

}
```